# sql developer connect to Timesten database

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, timesten

When I try to connect to the timesten databse using the SQL developer, I am getting following error message.

> Unrecognized JDBC URL subtype: TimesTen

I kept the `classes13.jar` in system classpath and also included in the `Tools - > preferences -> Database -> third party drivers`.

Is there anything I am missing in the setup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the ttjdbc5/ttjdbc6 depending on the jdk version selected during the timesten setup.